# How to mimic COUNTIF from MySQL to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that has columns A, B, and C, and I would like to count the occurrences of the A column, grouped by B and C.
DF Looks like this:

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

In MySQL I would do:

```
SELECT
B,
C,
COUNT(IF(A=1, 1,0)) AS CountEquals1,
COUNT(IF(A=0, 1,0)) AS CountEquals0
FROM
my_table
GROUP BY 
B, C;
```

How do I perform this same MySQL Count/GroupBy query on my Pandas Dataframe?

edit:
Expected output would be something like:

| B | C | CountAEquals1 | CountAEquals0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.loc[:,'A':'C'].value_counts()
.unstack(level=0)
.rename('CountAEquals{}'.format,axis=1)
.fillna(0)
.sort_index(axis=1,ascending=False)
.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   B  C  CountAEquals1  CountAEquals0
0  1  1            1.0            3.0
1  2  1            0.0            1.0
2  2  3            1.0            1.0
3  4  3            0.0            1.0
4  4  4            1.0            1.0
```